# Does resolving a single fight round in A Touch of Evil also trigger "The Horseman Rides Tonight!" event?

Tags: a-touch-of-evil

When playing against the Spectral Horseman, if something in the game triggers a single fight round with the Villain, does the Spectral Horseman's "The Horseman Rides Tonight!" event take effect?

For example, here's the wording on the Deadly Encounter mystery card:

> Every Hero must immediately roll a D6. Whoever rolls the lowest (roll off if tied), must resolve a single Fight Round with the Villain. Instead of causing Wounds, each Hit done to the Villain gains 1 investigation for the Hero.

... and the text for "The Horseman Rides Tonight!" event:

> The Villain attacks! The Hero must immediately resolve a single Fight Round with the Villain. Instead of causing Wounds, each Hit done to the Villain gains 1 Investigation for the Hero. This does NOT cause a Showdown.
>
> ...
>
> After an Fight here (or even if there is no Fight), the Spectral Horseman moves along the shortest path to the Town Hall, Fighting every Hero along the way as normal for his Relentless Charge ability.

Is it just coincidence that the first part of the event reads almost exactly the same as the deadly encounter or should the Spectral Horseman make his ride to the Town Hall and attack all other Heroes along the way in the event of a card that triggers a single fight round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, (according to the [rules](http://www.flyingfrog.net/atouchofevil/pdf/ATOE_Rulebook_Web.pdf)) the [Deadly Encounter](http://flyingfrogwiki.com/ffpwiki/index.php?title=Card:Deadly_Encounter) mystery card will cause the [Spectral Horseman](http://flyingfrogwiki.com/ffpwiki/index.php?title=Villain:Spectral_Horseman) to move along the shortest path to the Town Hall, Fighting every Hero along the way as **normal** for his Relentless Charge ability. The card "[The Horseman Rides Tonight](http://flyingfrogwiki.com/ffpwiki/index.php?title=Chart:%22The_Horseman_Rides_Tonight!%22)!" specifically tells you to do so, and Deadly Encounter causes a **Fight**. (emphasis mine)

> [Relentless Charge](http://flyingfrogwiki.com/ffpwiki/index.php?title=ATOE_Ability:Relentless_Charge) - At the end of **any fight** with the Spectral Horseman, he will ride the shortest route directly to the Town Hall, engaging in one fight round against any Hero moved over.

Unless it is canceled, **The Horseman Rides Tonight" event will take place.

> Many times a card will allow you to cancel another card as it is played or that Remains in Play.  As noted earlier, an Event Card may not be canceled after it has already caused dice to be rolled or rerolled.  Mystery Cards may always be canceled.

(**Note:** You actual ask, can the Mystery Card cancel the event, but that Mystery Phase  would happen after the event "The Horseman Rides Tonight" is played. So it would make more sense to ask, can The Horseman Rides Tonight" Event Card, cancel the Mystery Card Deadly Encounter.)

> Events are played as fast effect style cards and, unless noted otherwise, may be played at any time.
>
> In each Game Round, every player (starting with the First Player) takes their Hero
> Turn in order, moving clockwise around the table. Once each Hero has finished, there is a **Mystery Phase** in which the Villain gets to unleash some evil on the Heroes in the form of drawing a Mystery Card and reading it aloud.